# GIT push only commits older than x months

Tags: git

Is there a way to specify push commits that are older than x months to remote y ?
Like setting up a branch that automatically tracks master-(x months) and then push it to a separate remote?

Answer (score 1):

That could be rather tricky since commits aren't strictly date ordered. But, it sounds like you're not worried about exact precision. In that case, you can do something like this: Assume you want to push to the `master` branch on a remote named `foobar` from your current branch as of 6 months ago:

```
git push separate-remote @{6.months.ago}:master
```